# Best practice for putting javascript files behind user authentication?

Tags: php, javascript, security, authentication

I have a web app where most of the functionality is within a javascript file, and I am about to introduce a pro version of the app in which registered users would get access to more functionality.

Again the extra functionalities are just extra functions in a javascript file.

What I am planning to do is:
- link pro_script.js if user is logged in,
- or link to normal_script.js if user is not logged in,
at the header of the page via user authentication with php.

I was wondering if this is the best way to approach this situation?

I have concerns that the pro_script.js is residing accessible under the javascripts folder, and it would be possible to write a script or plugin that loads the pro_script.js instead of normal_script.js.

Comment: How do you handle authenticated users? Session, cookie, querystring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have your HTML to call `my_script.php` instead of my_script.js. This PHP file would simply output your JS depending on the state if the user is logged on or not.

Comment: Good idea, i made a quick research and found out that outputing JS with php requires me to echo the script line by line, escaping quotes and adding \n for each new line. If that is the case my javascript file is way to long to do that and if I did it, it would be very hard to work on the javascript code in the future.

Comment: @fahrio: not necessarily. PHP can be embedded in ANY text-based file. The PHP parser will only kick in on `<?php ... ?>` blocks, so you can have a pure .js file with only a small bit of PHP at the top for authentication. There's no need for line-by-line echoing, just pop out of php mode (`?>`) when you're done with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide pro_script.js behind PHP script - it will check user's account and if user is "premium" then it outputs content of pro_script.js, otherwise - empty string. Don't forget to setup correct headers (content-type and caching)

Answer (score 2):

This is acually @Adnan's idea, but my response was far to complex for a comment.

Your `my_script.php` should look something like this:

```
<?php 
session_start();
header("Content-type: application/x-javascript";);

if (!empty($_SESSION['PRO_USER'])) {
    echo file_get_contents("js/pro_script.js");
} else {
    echo file_get_contents("js/normal_script.js");
}

exit;
?>
```